# I have an Excel VBA macro that copies/paste and Excel formula to another file. The formula is this:

Tags: excel, vba

High level summary of problem: VBA is putting double quotes around a string that it copies from Excel which I don't want. I believe this piece of the string ($billtyp,) is causing VBA to put double quotes around it. In particular the comma at the end. I am in no way a programmer. Just hacking to automate some work for one of the ladies in our office. I greatly appreciate the help!

VBA code to follow. The Excel value and formula are these:

```
What I want:
ADDLABEL -files zTestCo.cli -labelrec $billtyp,Test1 -log I:\LOG\29-08-2017-Add Label-zTestCo.txt

What I get:
"ADDLABEL -files zTestCo.cli -labelrec $billtyp,Test1 -log I:\LOG\29-08-2017-Add Label-zTestCo.txt"
```

Excel Formula:

```
="ADDLABEL -files "&$C$1&".cli -labelrec $"&LOWER(B3)&","&C3&" -log I:\LOG\"&TEXT(NOW(),"dd-mm-yyyy")&"-Add Label-"&$C$1&".txt"
```

VBA Code:

```
Sub SetCustomLabels()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim fName As String

'References
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add

'Copy range on original sheet
wsSource.Range("J3:J50").Copy

'----------------------------
'Save in new workbook
wbDest.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Get file name and location from user
fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="I:\Axys3\auto\addLabel.scr", FileFilter:="Script Files (*.scr), *.scr", Title:="Save As")
If fName = "" Then Exit Sub '//user cancelled

'Save new tab delimited file
wbDest.SaveAs fName, xlText

wbDest.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to change `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` in `xlPasteFormulas`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I also tried xlPasteValues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test seems to work on my pc. Change the format in SaveAs:

From

```
wbDest.SaveAs fName, xlText
```

To

```
wbDest.SaveAs fName, xlTextPrinter
```

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much. I woke up earlier in the morning trying to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have a cheap and dirty solution - write the following formula and it would be exactly as you wish it:

```
=MID(C10,2,LEN(C10)-2)
```

The value in `C10` will be sliced with 1 char from start and end.

Comment: The double quotes do not show in Excel. When VBA paste them, then it shows. Just odd.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the clipboard in Excel you will see this behavior. In fact, Excel is doing its best to preserve your data. It will automatically encapsulate your copied string in double quotes if the string contains special characters like a tab, carriage return, or line feed so that when it's pasted to a cell the string isn't split.

As an alternative to the clipboard, you could just set the values of your "paste" range to the values of your "copy" range like:

```
wbDest.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A47") = wsSource.Range("J3:J50").value2
```

That would be in place of your `.copy` and `.pastespecial` lines.

If you must bring the number formats over as well, you could keep your existing `.copy` and `.pastespecial` lines and just change the paste special to `xlPasteNumberFormats` (I think that's the constant name)

Comment: I tried this, and I get PasteSpecial method of Range class failed. I adjusted the wbDest range to A1:A48 (47 rows) to match WsSource (47 rows) , but that did not help.